# Probability of a coin of $1$ cm diameter landing completely on a square cloth of side $2$ cm?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, open-problem

I have a coin of diameter $1$ cm, and I toss the coin over a square cloth of 2 cm by 2 cm.   Find the probability that the coin lands **completely** on the cloth i.e. no part of the coin lies outside the cloth.

Comment: Integrate the PDF of a 2D normal distribution over the unit sphere. The distribution must have zero mean, and the variance matrix must be a multiple of the identity matrix. $P=1-e^{-(2 a)^{-1}}$

Comment: Not correctly defined, is there a condition that the coin touches the square in at least one point? Or instead of one square the landing plane is tiled with infinite number of squares?

Comment: What do you know about the probability of the coin landing at any possible position? For instance, do you know that the center of the coin *always* lands on the cloth, and that all landing spots for the center are equally likely? If you aren't given that information (or something like it), then the answer depends a great deal on where you toss the coin --- if you toss it directly above one edge, the probability you're seeking will be much lower than if you toss it directly above the center, etc.

Comment: this is the complete question I got in one of my exams; and regarding the coin being tossed- The coin is tossed from a distance of 3 meters from the cloth towards the cloth, and if the coin lands completely on the cloth it's a favorable event. @JohnHughes

Comment: You have 1 cm radius in the title and 1 cm diameter in the question text. Assuming you have a $1$ cm radius coin per your title, there is only one way the $2$ cm diameter coin can completely land on the 2 cm square cloth and there are an infinity of ways it can't.

Comment: Boy...without any knowledge of the distribution, I'd say this one doesn't have an answer. If *I* were the one tossing, the probability would be nearly zero, because I have lousy aim. If you get a champion coin-tosser, it might be up to 5%, I suppose. If it really IS a 1 cm *diameter*, then the probability is easy to compute -- it's essentially got to be zero.